# how to use PDDocument.loadNonSeq, large pdf stripper/parsing text technique

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdftotext

I have some questions about parsing pdf anfd how to:

1. what is the purpose of using

`PDDocument.loadNonSeq` method that include a scratch/temporary file?

2. I have big pdf and i need to parse it and get text contents. I use `PDDocument.load()` and then *PDFTextStripper* to extract data page by page (pdfstripper have got `setStartPage(n)` and `setEndPage(n)`
   where n=n+1 every page loop ). Is more efficient for memory using  loadNonSeq instead load?

For example

```
File pdfFile =  new File("mypdf.pdf");
File tmp_file =  new File("result.tmp");
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(pdfFile, new RandomAccessFile(tmp_file, READ_WRITE));
int index=1;
int numpages = doc.getNumberOfPages();
for (int index = 1; index <= numpages; index++){
  PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        Writer destination = new StringWriter();
        String xml="";
        stripper.setStartPage(index);
        stripper.setEndPage(index);
        stripper.writeText(this.doc, destination);
.... //filtering text and then convert it in xml
}
```

Is this code above a right loadNonSeq use and is it a good practice to read PDF page per page without vaste in memory?
I use page per page reading because I need to write text in XML using DOM memory (using stripping technique, I decide to produce an XML for every page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. what is the purpose of using `PDDocument.loadNonSeq` method that include a scratch/temporary file?

PDFBox implements two ways to read a PDF file.

- `loadNonSeq` is the way documents should be loaded
- `load` is the way documents should not be loaded but one might try to repair flles with broken cross references this way

In the 2.0.0 development branch, the algorithm formerly used for `loadNonSeq` is now used for `load` and the algorithm formerly used for `load` is not used anymore.

> 2. I have big pdf and i need to parse it and get text contents. I use `PDDocument.load()` and then `PDFTextStripper` to extract data page by page (pdfstripper have got `setStartPage(n)` and `setEndPage(n)` where n=n+1 every page loop ). Is more efficient for memory using `loadNonSeq` instead `load`?

Using `loadNonSeq` instead of `load` may improve memory usage for multi-revision PDFs because it only reads objects still referenced from the reference table while `load` can keep more in memory.

I don't know, though, whether using a scratch file makes a big difference.

> is it a good practice to read PDF page per page without vaste in memory?

Internally PDFBox parses the given range page after page, too. Thus, if you process the stripper output page-by-page, it certainly is ok to parse it page by page.